# Is it possible to generate an object complete with keys using generator/ comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os

data = {}
for f in os.listdir('schools/'):
    data[f.replace('.csv','')] = pd.read_csv('schools/'+f)
```

I run into this often where I want to use a list comprehension of some kind, which i believe is possible using the format of...

```
{pd.read_csv('schools/'+f) for f in os.listdir('schools/')}
```

However, not sure how to get the keys in there? Is it possible to generate an object this way?

Comment: yes, with a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Hold the phone. What is your final goal? To concatenate all the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want a *dictionary comprehension*

```
for f in os.listdir('schools/'):
    data[f.replace('.csv','')] = pd.read_csv('schools/'+f)
```

becomes:

```
data = {f.replace('.csv',''):pd.read_csv(os.path.join('schools',f)) for f in os.listdir('schools')}
```

maybe made safer and more readable using `glob.glob` so you filter out non-csv files and you don't have to `join`:

```
data = {f.replace('.csv',''):pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(os.path.join('schools',"*.csv"))}
```

---

A slight extension, to convert this to a pandas dataframe (assuming each csv only has one column):

```
pd.DataFrame({f.replace('.csv','') : pd.read_csv(os.path.join('schools',f)).values.reshape(-1, ) for f in os.listdir('schools')})
```

Comment: If this is to become a pd data frame, you'll need to extend it a bit: `pd.DataFrame({f.replace('.csv',''): pd.read_csv(os.path.join('schools',f)).values.reshape(-1, ) for f in os.listdir('schools')})`... ew... looks ugly...

Comment: Yes. :P Typos are my bane.

Comment: feel free to edit my post to add that information, I'm not a `pandas` specialist at all.

Comment: i had been trying {f.replace('.csv','')=pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(os.path.join('schools',"*.csv"))} haha one of those homer simpson dooop moments.